# Is conference call possible with voIP Android

Tags: android, voip

I am developing an android application, to make conference call. I just want to know , does android supports conference call with voIP?

Answer (score 1):

Yes It is.

Starting APi Level 9, native SIP support was added to the framework which facilitates VoIP. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/package-summary.html

Here is a demo app: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SipDemo/index.html

Comment: Thankyou. I have gone through the links, But I have not found any conference call samples in  help documentation.

Comment: I have not worked on it. But I found this link "https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html" . Hope it may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the built-in VoIP client?
If not then there are a lot of SIP client libraries for Android (both paid and open source) and most of them comes with conference support.

Comment: Can you please give me some service provider website url, It would be great help.